# argparse — find out whether the argument was provided or default was used

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse, command-line-arguments

How to know whether the argument returned by `argparse` was given on command line, or default was used?

In the code below I want to know that `args` used default, but `args2` did not, although the provided value is the same as the default.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--khram', '-k', nargs='?', default='wawawiwa')

args = parser.parse_args([])
args2 = parser.parse_args(['-kwawawiwa'])
```

We can see that `args` and `args2` are indistinguishable:

```
>>> args == args2
True
>>> args.khram == args2.khram
True
>>> args._get_args() == args2._get_args()
True
>>> args._get_kwargs() == args2._get_kwargs()
True
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish but if you change `nargs` to `nargs=argparse.REMAINDER` then `args.khram` is equal to `[]` and `args2.khram` is equal `['wawawiwa']`

Comment: Pick a different default to use as a sentinel, then post-process the argument value to replace the sentinel with the "real" default.

Comment: If you want the default to behave differently from `'wawawiwa'`, then don't use `'wawawiwa'` as the default.

Comment: The default `default` is `None`.  The user cannot provide that value.  So `if args.khram is None:` is a safe test.   `parse_args` does maintain a `seen_actions` list, but it's local to the function, and not available to you.  The `args` Namespace is the only thing you have to work with.

Comment: As a point of detail.  `parse_args` assigns the defaults to the Namespace at the start of parsing.  If the argument is used, the user provided value is assigned to that Namespace attribute, over writing the default.  In other words, during parsing the user provided value overwrites the default.